Bounds on L1-norm of difference of two vectors
Given a $N \times N$ matrix $C$ and a vector $\rho = (\rho_1,\rho_2 \dots \rho_N)^{T}$ such that $$||C\rho||_1 = \Delta,$$ where the subscript $1$ denotes a L$1$-norm. We also have another vector $\rho' = (\rho'_1,\rho'_2 \dots \rho'_N)^{T}$ such that: $$ C\rho'= 0.$$ We are also given that all elements of $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are non-negative, and that $\sum_i \rho_i = \sum_i \rho'_i = 1$. Are there any non trivial upper and/or lower bounds on: $$||\rho - \rho'||_1$$ or on the expression: $$\left(\sum_i \sqrt{\rho_i\rho'_i}\right)^2.$$ I understand this can be drafted as a linear programming problem, but I cannot seem to find any relevant inequalities for systems of linear equations that help me with this.

I am unsure of the role of the matrix C in the question. Surely for any two independent vectors $r,r'$ and a constant $d$ you can find a matrix with the property that $Cr=d$ and $Cr'=0$? So I feel that your C does not impose any further constraints. Unless you expect the bounds searched for to include C somehow.

@Al.G. Yes, I think you are right. Even ideally, I would not want to expect the bounds to involve C anyhow, but the problem statement I have is defined for a given C, so that is that.
